# How to check if turpentine is working

Tags: varnish

I have installed varnish 3.0.5 as reverse proxy on my e-commerce website along with turpentine.How can I check if turpentine is working or not?

Comment: i have used magento 1.9.2 as cms

Comment: Define working.  Verify / measure results to see if they match definition.  (This post shows no effort as does this comment.)

Comment: Is there any specific commands to check turpentine's performance?